# What should I use to make this MOSFET drop the gate-voltage even faster?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, pwm

I'm trying to create a delay circuit like this.
When I snapp on the push button, then the current flows from +3.3V to GND and bypass the 220 Ohm resistor, which is my load.

But the problem here is that I want to have this current peaks like a square wave, PWM etc, not this slow slope.

**Question:**

What should I replace so this MOSFET got its voltage gate dropped to 0V when the gate voltag is under a certain threshold?

I will NOT use a mechanical relay and optocoupler will not work neither.

Digital circuits will work too. But I'm not expert at them.

[image]

**Solution:**

Schmitt-trigger

[image]

Comment: Remove capacitor. Use SPDT switch, common to transistor gate, two others to grounds and PS+.

Comment: Use a digital output to drive that gate directly with 0 V (off) or 3.3 V (on). Why is there a capacitor if you want fast switching? It is like filling a car with heavy stones and then complaining it doesn't accelerate that fast.

Comment: Define Delays for rising and falling edge and rise/fall time  with tolerances !

Comment: Hearing that you don't want that slope is confusing: Why exactly then are you using this exact circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wire is not defined on the schematic.   Typically Delays are made for Half Bridges to delay turn-on to avoid short circuit or shoot -thru and depend on load inductance and FET Capacitance which I modelled here for a power FET with Ciss.

The Turn-ON delay is circled and OFF is assumed to be x ns with low diode resistance.

[image]

You must define more details on FET parameters and load. [I simply chose beta=1 and logic level FET with Vt=1.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCAcB0CMBMBWApgWgJzmgFkgdllgDZF0z5tFs8BmPERCRBptQgKACcRswJ4KPPiHiRI4EfDDQ%20suXJrsA7kIg0pqkDRpFw7AGZbE8LWGyaaZrSdhZE7AEqaB5mscnmIEXlug0JXtD2AOYWOhbuXuwAxkYmlq7u2roQsNDwaJg00ER4eGA0YkSQpOiIsJ4yYLDKYbpu8eFgXHGm5vB48VZqluwAJq0dJkMinSIgsABy2BWQtQ2j8UndtSNrYwl6TiObLm0SJrxyIkEnzIH2KjO6ouJHImJ6APbjtqlI2LqIVfK-1ViyN6vN7sIA)

Comment: But you are using a PWM source at 400 kHz. I want to create a delay OFF function

Comment: By the way! Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Ok I guessed wrong what you were actually looking for and you still did not show the input to measure the delay